# Why is the Jacobian matrix the transpose of what I would think it'd be/usefully be (total derivative is a synonym) (EDIT: I was a total wally)

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, notation

I'm sorry this isn't a yes/no/am-I-right question but I seriously cannot see why the Jacobian/total derivative matrix is what it is?
I am also using it as LaTeX practice (for maths) hence the barely relevant blocks of math.

(note the terms in the title and this message is what I hope to get clarified, just incase they are wrong)

$f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$
and $f(x)=y$

I will use the notation of $x^i$ being the ith member of a vector x, that is:

$x=(x^1,x^2,x^3, ... ,x^k)$ for a vector of order/length k.

Consider also the linear map: (or should I say transform?)

$A:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$

Consider now $x,u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (I would use delta x for u, but then my notation could backfire)

The best linear approximation we can have for the ith coordinate of the image is:

$$f(x+u)^i = f(x)^i + \sum^n_{j=1}(\frac{\partial f(x)^i}{\partial x^j}u^j)$$

Which is basically the definition of a partial derivative. Nothing new here.

Clearly now:
$$f(x) + \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f(x)^1}{\partial x^1} &
\frac{\partial f(x)^1}{\partial x^2} &
...&
\frac{\partial f(x)^1}{\partial x^n} \\
\frac{\partial f(x)^2}{\partial x^1} &
\frac{\partial f(x)^2}{\partial x^2} &
...&
\frac{\partial f(x)^2}{\partial x^n} \\
...&...&...&...\\
\frac{\partial f(x)^m}{\partial x^1} &
\frac{\partial f(x)^m}{\partial x^2} &
...&
\frac{\partial f(x)^m}{\partial x^n}
\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}u^1\\u^2\\...\\u^n\end{bmatrix}
\approx f(x+u)$$

Let:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f(x)^1}{\partial x^1} &
\frac{\partial f(x)^1}{\partial x^2} &
...&
\frac{\partial f(x)^1}{\partial x^n} \\
\frac{\partial f(x)^2}{\partial x^1} &
\frac{\partial f(x)^2}{\partial x^2} &
...&
\frac{\partial f(x)^2}{\partial x^n} \\
...&...&...&...\\
\frac{\partial f(x)^m}{\partial x^1} &
\frac{\partial f(x)^m}{\partial x^2} &
...&
\frac{\partial f(x)^m}{\partial x^n}
\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}u^1\\u^2\\...\\u^n\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}v^1\\v^2\\...\\v^m\end{bmatrix}$$

Then:

$f(x+u)\approx y+v$

That is a pretty compelling case for not transposing it!

If you transpose it you can then use row-vectors and pre-multiply, rather than post, but column-vectors and linear algebra are something that is so well established, I wont restate.

Now the total derivative matrix is listed in my notes (quite correctly IMO) as what I've just put above.

Writing it like I have above looks nice, because now let that matrix be A:

$f(x+u) \approx f(x)+Au$ isn't that lovely!

The "Jacobian of a transformation" however is written as "the determinant of the transpose of this matrix" and I must ask WHY?
Transposing a matrix does not affect it's determinant! I cannot find any reason to transpose it UNLESS there is some notation I don't know about where:

$$\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}$$ = some 2x2 matrix that is the transpose of what I claim it ought to be.

But my book says the above denotes a determinant <---NOT a matrix

So why might I want to transpose it?

Unless there are several things with "Jacobian" in the name maybe, could someone correct me!

Edit:

The books consider $A^T$ as the Jacobian Matrix (?) and "The Jacobian of the transformation" is defined using the determinant of that matrix, which is written as just:

$$\frac{\partial (y^1,y^2,...,y^n)}{\partial(x^1,x^2,..,x^n)}$$

Obviously in this case n=m

**I WAS A HUGE DIPSTICK**
I'm so sorry guys, this has wasted everyone's time, 'cept maybe John's.....

In the 2x2 case:

$$r_1=x_1-x_0 = (\frac{\partial x}{\partial u},\frac{\partial y}{\partial u})\Delta u$$

$$r_2=x_2-x_0 = (\frac{\partial x}{\partial v},\frac{\partial y}{\partial v})\Delta v$$

You can then find the area as $\lVert r_1 \times r_2\rVert$

And
$$r_1\times r_2 = det\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} &
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}
\\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} &
\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\end{bmatrix} . \Delta u\Delta v\boldsymbol{k}$$

It is talking about the transpose of that!

I am so sorry everyone!

Comment: I know a) Jacobian matrix, which is the matrix of the total derivative (if $f$ is differentiable, the corresponding matrix of partial derivatives if $f$ is only partially differentiable), and b) the determinant of that matrix in case of equal dimensions. Nothing with "transpose". Which book?

Comment: People use the transpose because when you change coordinates in an integral, you use the *pullback* of the volume form. Working on an answer now.

Comment: Can you upload some pictures of what your books writes? I don't think it is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have always used what you first have (without the transpose) as the Jacobian. It is in every book I have seen. It is also the definition on wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant

So basically, you are right, where ever you are reading it is wrong.

Comment: I'm glad, I really can't get my head around why it says "We defined the Jacobian of the transformation as the determinant of this matrix transposed" you can't typo that, and the matrix it transposes is mine, and the one it does the determinant of is my one, transposed! Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @AlecTeal Note that there is often (always?) a distinction between "Jacobian" and "Jacobian matrix", and that the former is a determinant (i.e. not a matrix).

Comment: "So basically, you are right, where ever you are reading it is wrong." I think you've rushed to a conclusion.

Comment: @Peter: Yeah you're probably right. Though as you describe in your answer it is the transpose of, what most sources call, the Jacobian matrix, not the standard usage of Jacobian matrix.

Answer (score 7):

The Jacobian matrix tends to show up in two places: As linear approximation of a map, and in change-of-variables of an integral.

Your explanation of the approximation of a map is correct and you have the formula right, as long as you're representing $\mathbb{R}^n$ with column vectors.

However, in a change of variables, we use the transpose of the Jacobian. Here's why. Let's say we're integrating some function $\phi$ over a domain $\Omega$:
$$\int_\Omega \phi \omega$$
where $\omega$ is the volume form on $\Omega$ (it takes $n$ vector fields and returns a function describing the infinitesimal volume spanned by the vector fields at each point ). In coordinates $x^i$ on $\Omega$, $\omega = dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge\cdots dx^n$.

If we change variables, we *precompose* $\phi$ with a diffeomorphism $f$ and get
$$\int_{f^{-1}\Omega}(\phi\circ f)\ f^*\omega.$$
Here $f^*\omega$ is the pullback of the volume form $\omega$, which is defined by taking $n$ vector fields, pushing them through $df$, then feeding them to $\omega$. In coordinates, $f^*\omega = (f^*dx^1)\wedge (f^*dx^2)\wedge\cdots\wedge (f^*dx^n)$.

That is, $f^*\omega$ is the wedge of the pullbacks of all $n$ coordinate one-forms. Now, in coordinates, a one-form can be represented as a row vector, just as a vector field can be represented as a column vector, and the action of one-forms on vector fields is simply matrix multiplication. The pullback of a one-form, say, $\eta$, is defined by $f^*\eta(v) = \eta(df(v))$. In coordinates, first multiply $v$ by $df$, then multiply by the column vector $\eta$:
$$(\ \ \ \eta\ \ \ )\bigg(\ \ \ df\ \ \ \bigg)\bigg(v\bigg).$$
But if we want the coordinates of $\eta$, represent $\eta$ as a vector and use the transpose: $\eta = (df^T\eta^T)^T$.

So $f^*\omega = (df^Tdx^1)^T\wedge\cdots\wedge(df^Tdx^n)^T$. Whenever you have the $n$-fold wedge product of vector fields, take the determinant of the matrix of the vector fields: $f^*\omega = (\det df^T)dx^1\wedge\cdots dx^n$. So that's why the transpose shows up.

Comment: Neal this was (probably) a great answer, going by the amount I didn't understand (I'm reading into that right now) usually when I have a change of variables in an integral the volume form (length->area->volume ... generalised to a thing called a "volume form" I guess?) is simply |A|da db dc (...) where M is the matrix above, transposing wouldn't affect this, so the sub-question here is if I wanted to read about the thing you wrote (find out how it is different, thus why it exists/we may use it) what do I search for? thanks @Neal

Comment: Sorry, I think this is a pretty poor answer. A concrete approach is in the book *Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms* by Hubbard & Hubbard. For a more advanced approach, consider reading the chapter on forms in Rudin.

Answer (score 3):

It is simply because they don't transpose the vector you feed and do transpose the Jacobian, and conversely, those who don't transpose the Jacobian transpose the vector. This is because $$(A\cdot v)^t=v^t\cdot A^t$$

and your book simply uses the right hand side of the equation as opposed to using the left hand side. Note that in all your equalities you are transposing the column vector, which is what made you think something was wrong. You write $A\cdot v=w$ where both $w$ are column vectors, but then write them with the same letter as row vectors. For example, if we agree to write $f=(f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n)$ as a *row* vector, the product in this equation $$f(x) + \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f(x)^1}{\partial x^1} &
\frac{\partial f(x)^1}{\partial x^2} &
...&
\frac{\partial f(x)^1}{\partial x^n} \\
\frac{\partial f(x)^2}{\partial x^1} &
\frac{\partial f(x)^2}{\partial x^2} &
...&
\frac{\partial f(x)^2}{\partial x^n} \\
...&...&...&...\\
\frac{\partial f(x)^m}{\partial x^1} &
\frac{\partial f(x)^m}{\partial x^2} &
...&
\frac{\partial f(x)^m}{\partial x^n}
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}u^1\\u^2\\...\\u^n\end{pmatrix}
\approx f(x+u)$$

is a column vector, so what you write makes no sense. Of course, one can write them as column vectors, as things are just OK. It is simply a matter of convention!

Alternatively, as you suggest, $$f({\bf x})^t+\left({\bf D}f({\bf x})\cdot {\bf u}^t\right)^t\simeq f({\bf x+u})^t $$is correct assuming we're working with row vetors.

And in that case, this is the same as

$$f({\bf x})+{\bf u}\cdot{\bf D}f({\bf x})^t \simeq f({\bf x+u})$$

which is presumably what your book writes, that is, your book works with row vectors all the way and transposes the matrix to make things work.

Comment: I disagree with the middle part, f(x) is a column vector (of length m) as is the product of the mxn (m down, n across) x a nx1 vector is an m x 1 matrix (or vector) and f(x+u) will be f(nx1) = mx1

Comment: @AlecTeal I usually write functions as row vectors. Maybe this is just a big lack of consensus! =)

Comment: I tend to write them rows but I use commas and take them to mean "column vectors that fit inline" BUT I do use that notation for Makov Chains.... having said that it seems I will always be using the determinant of the matrix, so I really do wonder why the transpose. Hmm...

Comment: @AlecTeal The moral of this is: be consistent with your notation, and that is all. I don't think one should push this any further.

Comment: yes it is kind of a null question, I like Neal's answer because it basically says "You'll find out later in your education" but there is a meaning! Thanks for your help.

Comment: see the addition, I was really silly, sorry for wasting your time.